# Oracle Sql developer error: could not install some modules

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have downloaded a fresh copy of sqldeveloper (**sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-no-jre**) from the Oracle website. When I unzip it and lauch the GUI, I keep getting the following error  message:

> Warning - could not install some modules: Dynamic Module Config - No
>   module providing the capability org.netbeans.Netbinox could be found.

My system:

- Windows 7 32 bit Hp Probook.
- Jdk 1.6 , 1.7, 1.8 available in java/jdk
  subdirectory.
- Netbeans 8.0.2 installed

Comment: we use some netbeans stuff

Comment: @thatjeffsmith can you elaborate more on your comment ? We are really blocked by this error....

Comment: SQLDev is largely built on JDeveloper IDE Platform. That platform also has some Netbeans components included. Your error generally sounds like a 'bad install' - it got extracted in such a way that one or more of the files or components couldn't be found.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Finally got the way out after some dirty hours. Initially I extracted the sqldeveloper zip in a nested directory.

i.e: E://A/B/C/sqldeveloper.
starting sqldeveloper gui from the above directory threw erros.

Solution:

- Go in C:\users**UserName**\AppData\Roaming : delete SQL Developer and sqldeveloper folders
- Extract the Sql Developer zip in a new non nested directory. i.e: E://
- Start it and should work now

Reference: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3870680?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: thanks, this is work then i want to add more trick, if this instalation on child folder please check your parent folder, the name of parent could not use any symbol, just within space, number and (upper or lower) font.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very old post but I have had the same issue recently on version 22.2, and this might help.

**WARNING: You may lose important settings with this solution.**
Try deleting the *system cache* under *C:\Users<your_user_name>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\{whatever}*
(or simply everything in that folder). This solved the problem for me, but obviously you do lose configuration settings, connections, and so on, ie, everything you've ever done in SQL Developer - so be careful.

Comment: I clenad all the folders that were named system_cache* under the current version folder, I had to do it after using for a while the graalvm that used I guess different formats in the cache

Comment: I was able to remove the `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system<version>\system_cache\config` directory to resolve this error while still keeping my saved connections.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was enough to change JDK pass to Java 8 in the 
C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\19.2.1\product.conf file:
SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

I have Java 13 as default and although SQL developer complained at startup it worked OK with it until I started it and went away from the computer, so I missed the warning screen. After that it started to show the "could not install the modules" error.

Comment: I have similar error and your solution works for me.

Answer (score 3):

To optimize the answer of all others which is to delete the cached files, deleting the files under `Module` folder is enough. The whole address is as `C:\Users\<YOUR_USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system<YOUR_SQLDEVELOPER_VERSION>\system_cache\config\Modules`. Delete whatever exists in that folder.

Answer (score 2):

For those that are working on a linux machine, for me worked just changing the jdk version that I'm currently using. I change went to the path `usr/lib/jvm/` and look for the versions that my pc have. Then in `~/.sqldeveloper/"yourversion"/product.conf` I changed the Java home to java-8-openjdk (It was using the 11 version)

Answer (score 2):

In my case renaming/deleting only this folder was good enough:
C:\Users*username*\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system22.2.0.173.2018
This way I could still import old connections after starting sqldeveloper again

Comment: Worked for me, as well. To restore your connections, you can backup system<version>\o.jdeveloper.db.connection\connections.json and copy it back after removing the folder and starting SQL Developer once.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [This](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Could-not-install-some-modules-td3323098.html) I just deleted `mypath\sqldeveloper\netbeans\platform\modules\org-netbeans-core-windows.jar` and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was getting this error after I reinstalled java while keeping an instance of sqldeveloper running.
After I ended the running instance, then I could start a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, so when the could not install some modules board shows up, click the disable modules and continue, then immediately open the app again it should work :)))

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32343141)

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was to unzip the SQL developer in a directory without special characters.

At first, I had exported it in a directory that included the hash (`#`) symbol.

I now have it in a nested directory again, without any special characters, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

generalized folder to remove in Windows (e.g. Amazon WorkSpace) Clients:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\
```

Answer (score 0):

On linux, I fixed this problem by deleting .sqldeveloper folder in the home directory as follows

```
rm -rf ~/.sqldeveloper
```

Please note that this will clear all your preferences and saved data including saved connections.